# Better way to do undefined and createElement in JS

Tags: javascript

Is there a better or cleaner way to write the following code in JS?

```
var element = document.getElementById("abc");
if (element === undefined) {
   var element = document.createElement("div");
   element.id="abc";
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty clean to me. Except you would use `let` instead of `var`, and leave the second `var` off to reuse the same variable.

Comment: You shouldn't be comparing to *undefined* at all. If there's no element with ID "abc" then *document.getElementById* returns *null*, so you should compare to that (though in practice it doesn't make any difference and `if (!element){...}` would suffice). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let element = document.getElementById("abc");
if (!element) {
   element = document.createElement("div");
   element.id="abc";
}
```

Note:- I think your question code is right but to be more specific some changes.

Comment: `const`should be `let`. My browser complains when I run the snippet : Assignment to const variable

Comment: @HBP , Thank you, Sir, Changed :-)

Answer (score 2):

To exactly duplicate your example code :

```
let element = document.getElementById ("abc") || document.createElement ("div");
element.id="abc";
```

or if this is the only action you need for the element

```
(document.getElementById ("abc") || document.createElement).id) = "abc";
```

However be aware that if the `createElement` is executed, the new element will not appear in your document.

Comment: "*if this is the only action you need for the element*" seems unlikely. I can't see a reason to create an element and assign it an ID, then not keep a reference to it.